# how to modify captcha image source in yii?

Tags: php, yii, captcha

my captcha images is not diplayed, this is the url of it:

`mysite.com/index.php/site/captcha?v=53b56139cb358`, when I am trying to open it I get an

error:

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/patrahr/public_html/index.php:1)`

function actions:

```
public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),
            // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
            // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }
```

so how I can fix this error ?

Comment: What's the rest of the error? Can you also post the `public function actions()` method in your SiteController?

Comment: do you have an `echo` on your index page or in a config file maybe?

Comment: @deacs no, there is no any echo

Comment: How about an empty line before the PHP start tag?

Answer (score 1):

When this problem occurs fast you have que convert the paragraph UTF-8 without BOM !

Use Notepad ++ To Do This procedure .